# input type text not working on popup

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a contact us form to be used on my website, it's a popup like style using css onclick methods to display or hide the form.
when opening the form in a unique tab it works properly, but when using it as a popup I can not use the text boxes to enter the information, the text box is selected but I cannot write any text in it.
This is my website http://www.tilalfaqra.com/new
Try clicking on contact us on the main page then this URI http://www.tilalfaqra.com/new/signin.php

Comment: you have issues in this function "caseStudy.updatePositionInfo".. If it is not required just remove it from this line number 483 of file "case-studyeef3.js".. remove this, "caseStudy.updatePositionInfo();"

Answer (score 0):

If you enter within a browser (Opera) click on the textfield and Inspect Element. You will see this js error logged:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined case-studyeef3.js?v=0.3:458caseStudy.updatePositionInfo case-studyeef3.js?v=0.3:458(anonymous function) case-studyeef3.js?v=0.3:483st.event.dispatch jquery.js:3045y.handle
```

The eror is located in this js function.

```
caseStudy.updatePositionInfo = function () {
        currentRowXY = currentRow.position();
        currentRowLeft = currentRowXY.left;
        imgScrollerXY = imgScroller.position();
        imgScrollerTop = imgScrollerXY.top;
    };
```